# LINQ query including an array of long type data

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, contains

I have a Ling query and in this query I want to fetch data according to data in an array (`PrdIdArr`).

In the 6th line `u.START_PRD_ID` should be matched with data in the array (`PrdIdArr`) but I could not

```
var mainQuery = (from o in db.OPERATIONs
                join u in db.UNITs on o.OP_UNIT_ID equals u.UNIT_ID
                join x in db.XIDs on u.UNIT_ID equals x.UNIT_ID
                where o.OP_OT_CODE == OtCode
                where x.IDTYP_CD == "BSN"
                **where u.START_PRD_ID == PrdIdArr[0]**
                where u.START_PRD_ID == new List<long>(PrdIdArr.Any<long>)
                select new
                {
                    ...

                }).Take(_RowNumber);
var result = mainQuery.ToList();
data = this.Json(result);
data.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;

return data;
```

I could not make the correct way of matching the data of a field (`u.START_PRD_ID`) with each data in an array (`PrdIdArr`)!

Can anyone help me, please???

Answer (score 0):

if you want to wish to get those fields that contain in both the query and array, use intercept?

```
 var c = a.Intersect(b);
```

However, the above will remove the duplicates field.

you could also use contains

```
b.Contains(a)
```